# How to connect to localhost api?

Tags: ios, swift, api, localhost

This is my code:

```
class MovieService: ObservableObject {
    func getAllMovies() {
        guard let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:7056/api/Movies/GetMovies") else {
            return;
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body:[String: AnyHashable] = [
            "page":1,
            "pageSize":25,
            "genreId":0,
            "yearId":0,
            "seachValue":"",
        ]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(response)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
2023-03-18 01:26:44.695576+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] \[\] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2023-03-18 01:26:44.696844+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] \[connection\] nw_socket_handle_socket_event \[C1.1:2\] Socket SO_ERROR \[61: Connection refused\]
2023-03-18 01:26:44.700470+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] \[connection\] nw_socket_handle_socket_event \[C1.2:2\] Socket SO_ERROR \[61: Connection refused\]
2023-03-18 01:26:44.701635+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] Connection 1: received failure notification
2023-03-18 01:26:44.702876+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] Connection 1: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2023-03-18 01:26:44.703112+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] Connection 1: encountered error(1:61)
2023-03-18 01:26:44.706704+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820350\] Task \<44020F8F-D4B7-477E-9304-96F513A0A80E\>.\<1\> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 \[1:61\])
2023-03-18 01:26:44.725204+0100 WhatchMoviesOnline\[46545:3820356\] Task \<44020F8F-D4B7-477E-9304-96F513A0A80E\>.\<1\> finished with error \[-1004\] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={\_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000351c9c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={\_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, \_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=
"LocalDataTask \<44020F8F-D4B7-477E-9304-96F513A0A80E\>.\<1\>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:7056/api/Movies/GetMovies, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:7056/api/Movies/GetMovies, \_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Comment: reformat the code in your question, it is unreadable. Note, Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server. Have you done that?

Comment: Also keep in mind that this will only work when you run the app in the simulator. This is not going to work when you run your app on a real iOS device unless your app is also running its own embedded web server.

Comment: @FahimParkar "localhost" means just that, it's the local host - the same machine that the app is running on. If the app is running in the simulator then localhost is the Mac. If the app is running on an iPhone then localhost is that same iPhone. That's why I said it will only work on a real iOS device if the same app is running its own embedded web server